# Magento error message alignment issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, css

As per my client requirement i have crated a custom theme, in that the home page error message have a alignment issue.

I need my error message top to the label.

For your information i attached the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code from

```
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?></h1>
</div>
 <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

Update it to,

```
 <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
 <div class="page-title">
   <h1><?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?></h1>
 </div>
```